# Automatically add the author date in prepare-commit-msg in GIT

Tags: git, bash, git-tf

I am looking for a way to add the author date to the commit message in GIT, using the prepare-commit-msg hook. This is necessary for a GIT->TFS migration workaround. I came up with the following script, but I couldn't find a way to reference the *current* commit, so that it would work properly.

```
#!/bin/sh
git show -s --format="<timestamp>%ai</timestamp>" %curcommit >> $1
```

What should I insert instead of %curcommit in order for the script to work as intended?

Comment: Take a look at the `--date` option to `git commit`, as well as the `commit.template` configuration option documented in `git help config`. One or the other should help you out.

Comment: What git operation are you doing, when you expect the hook to do this?